# C++ глобальный enum

Tags: c++

Как создать enum который будет доступен везде? Я вот например создал enum и с ним все нормально работает в классах где создаю а вот в класе наследнике если сказать, что метод хочет что-небуть типа enum'a, получаю ошибку что enum is not type name?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Код вашего enuma и класса приведите в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Объявить в **.h** файле `enum`.

**myenum.h**:

```
#ifndef MYENUM_H
#define MYENUM_H

enum myenum {ONE, TWO};

#endif
```

`#ifndef и #define` позволяет подключать `enum` где угодно, чтоб конфликтов не было.

Где надо, подключать:

```
#include "myenum.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень жаль, что вы положились на наши телепатические способности и не привели код. Поэтому приходится просто гадать, что же вы не так делаете.

Как видите, вот код с наследованием, в котором `enum`, объявленный в базовом классе, виден наследнику:

```
class Base
{
public:
    enum Enum { ONE = 1, TWO, THREE };
public:
    void f(Enum e) {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void g(Enum e) {}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    d.g(Base::ONE);
}
```

Если это не натолкнет вас на правильные выводы, пожалуйста, исправьте свой вопрос - как семантически, так и синтаксически, кстати говоря :) При невнятном ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...